# QGIS Map Tips Keep Open

Tags: qgis-3, maptips

I am using HTML code under a Layer's Properties -> Display to show a maptip on hover that includes a picture.

Previously, when I hovered over, the maptip would show, and let me hover over it and click a link on the bubble. That has stopped for some reason.

I see in Settings -> Options -> Canvas & Legend I can specify the delay before a maptip opens (in ms) but not for how long it should stay open.

Like I said, this is a new problem, so either I changed a setting somewhere accidentally, or a recent update changed a setting.

Using QGIS 3.8.2

Comment: Try increasing the search radius (in Options > Map Tools > Identify) for the Identify tool and Map Tips.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it is indeed a changed behaviour. In 3.8.1, the maptips would remain when you hovered over a feature but in 3.8.2, the maptips disappear when moving the mouse cursor out from the maptip box.

This issue was recently raised:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31311

---

A workaround was also suggested:

> There is a work-around: by right-clicking on the point after the map tip
>   opens. This opens a dialog for the selection of which layer to show the
>   identify feature dialog for, then it is possible to left click in the map
>   tip dialog and the map tip dialog stays open so that links can be clicked.
>   Much different than the way the map tip functioned in 3.8.1.